# Two rows in two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table:

| Owner | Book | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Vile Bodies by Evelyn Waugh | 2009-05-20 |
| Tom | Vile Bodies by Evelyn Waugh | 2009-05-22 |
| Jim | Moab is my Washpot by Stephen Fry | 2009-05-26 |
| Kate | Moab is my Washpot by Stephen Fry | 2009-06-02 |

How can I get table:

| Owner | Book | Pick_Date | Gave_Back_Book_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Vile Bodies by Evelyn Waugh | 2009-05-20 | 2009-05-22 |
| Tom | Vile Bodies by Evelyn Waugh | 2009-05-22 |  |
| Jim | Moab is my Washpot by Stephen Fry | 2009-05-26 | 2009-06-02 |
| Kate | Moab is my Washpot by Stephen Fry | 2009-06-02 |  |

Comment: I don't get it, you just take the first next date for any book as return date of the previous owner?

Comment: Yes. It was mistake in second table. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the `lead()` [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) which allows you to access columns from the "next" row(s)

```
select owner, book, "date" as pick_date, 
       lead(date) over (partition by book order by "date") as return_date
from the_table
order by book, "date"
```

Talking about the "next" row only makes sense if the rows are sorted, that's why the `order by "date"` is needed in the definition of the window

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter the table with

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype;
```

for adding a column, or

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY column_name datatype;
```

for modify it.
Then you have to alter every line of the table that is already into it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The main problem is that I want to get second table with query.

Comment: As it is currently written, it does not answer the question. The OP was asking for a solution based on logic expressed using SQL, not the syntax to add new column to a table.